# Filtering inside a processing method vs. filtering outside

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

In my application I am processing a List of `IMyInterface`  instances. Not all, but some of them **in addition** also implement `IAnotherInterface`. Note that `IAnotherInterface` not derives from `IMyInterface`. Following the Single Responsibility Principle, I have a separate class that processes the `IMyInterfaces` instances via a `Process` method. Now I am struggling with the design choice whether

1. the signature should be `Process(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> items)` and I filter for `IAnotherInterface` inside this method
2. or the signature should be `Process(IEnumerable<IAnotherInterface> items)`, meaning the filtering has to be done outside the processing method by the "client".

To make it more clear, these are the two code options I am struggling between:

```
// alternative 1:
List<MyInterface> items = GetItems(); // code not shown here
foreach(var item in items)
{
    // do some other processing before, not shown here

    // pass items to Process(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> items)
    myProcessor.Process(items);                
            
    // do some other processing afterwards, not shown here
}

// or alternative 2:
List<MyInterface> items = GetItems(); // code not shown here
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // do some other processing before, not shown here

    // pass items to Process(IEnumerable<IAnotherInterface> items)
    // -> need to filter first
    var filteredItems = filterForIAnotherInterface(items);
    myProcessor.Process(filteredItems);

    // do some other processing afterwards, not shown here
}
```

Is there any good reasoning for choosing one over the other? My own thoughts are that alternative 1 is easier to use for the client, but then the `Process` method has to do filtering which adds some kind of an additional responsibility besides its main responsibility. On the other hand, alternative 2 in some way makes the processing pipeline less readable I think.

Comment: Filter outside. Especially if the two interfaces are rather unrelated, filter outside. You can _make_ that readable by giving it a reasonably named filter (extesion?-) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no absolute rules to guide an API design decision like that. On the one hand, you may want to be as explicit as possible.

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> - [The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

Another way to put this is to apply the [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If you had a method with the signature `void Process(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> items)`, client code would expect such a method to process `IMyInterface` objects. Such a client might be surprised, then, if it passes a collection of `IMyInterface` objects that *do not* also implement `IAnotherInterface` and then *nothing happens*. Surprising.

On the other hand, the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) (Postel's law) might argue that if `Process` can handle `IMyInterface` objects, then it should also accept them.

---

Since I don't know more than what's in the OP, it doesn't sound as though Postel's law *really* applies here, since the `Process` method actually doesn't *handle* any `IMyInterface` objects - it just ignores them.

Thus, without knowing more than that, it sounds as thought the API should be `void Process(IEnumerable<IAnotherInterface> items)`.

> On the other hand, alternative 2 in some way makes the processing pipeline less readable I think.

Just use [OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype):

```
myProcessor.Process(items.OfType<IAnotherInterface>());
```

If you really want to make the pipeline explicit, you could invert the arguments by introducing an (internal) extension method:

```
public static void ProcessWith(
    this IEnumerable<IAnotherInterface> items,
    SomeProcessor processor)
{
    processor.Process(items);
}
```

which would enable you to write the pipeline like this:

```
items.OfType<IAnotherInterface>().ProcessWith(myProcessor);
```

Comment: Thank you and @Fildor for your thoughts. I really like the arguments and extension method ideas.